# grails app standalone app with searchable plug-in throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-searchable, grails-2.5

I'm trying to build a standalone grails (v.2.5.0) app using the grails [standalone app runner plug-in](https://grails.org/plugin/standalone) (v.1.3). With run-app and run-war everything works fine and I can also deploy the WAR file to a tomcat 7 instance without any issues. However, if I build a standalone JAR with grails build-standalone I cannot start the JAR due to the following ClassNotFoundException:

```
2015-08-17 10:52:48,523 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'searchableMethodFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'compass' while setting bean property 'compass'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'compass': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: grails/plugin/searchable/internal/compass/mapping/DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder$_buildClassMappingXml_closure1$_closure4$_closure12$_closure13
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'searchableMethodFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'compass' while setting bean property 'compass'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'compass': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: grails/plugin/searchable/internal/compass/mapping/DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder$_buildClassMappingXml_closure1$_closure4$_closure12$_closure13
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'compass': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: grails/plugin/searchable/internal/compass/mapping/DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder$_buildClassMappingXml_closure1$_closure4$_closure12$_closure13
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: grails/plugin/searchable/internal/compass/mapping/DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder$_buildClassMappingXml_closure1$_closure4$_closure12$_closure13
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.mapping.DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder$_buildClassMappingXml_closure1$_closure4$_closure12.doCall(DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder.groovy:188)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.mapping.DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder$_buildClassMappingXml_closure1$_closure4.doCall(DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder.groovy:187)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.mapping.DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder$_buildClassMappingXml_closure1.doCall(DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder.groovy:72)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.mapping.DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder.buildClassMappingXml(DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder.groovy:65)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.config.mapping.SearchableClassPropertySearchableGrailsDomainClassMappingConfigurator.configureMappings(SearchableClassPropertySearchableGrailsDomainClassMappingConfigurator.java:99)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.config.DefaultGrailsDomainClassMappingSearchableCompassConfigurator.configure(DefaultGrailsDomainClassMappingSearchableCompassConfigurator.java:140)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.config.CompositeSearchableCompassConfigurator.configure(CompositeSearchableCompassConfigurator.java:39)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.spring.SearchableCompassFactoryBean.buildCompass(SearchableCompassFactoryBean.java:93)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.spring.SearchableCompassFactoryBean.getObject(SearchableCompassFactoryBean.java:58)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.spring.SearchableCompassFactoryBean.getObject(SearchableCompassFactoryBean.java:41)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.mapping.DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder$_buildClassMappingXml_closure1$_closure4$_closure12$_closure13
    ... 14 more
2015-08-17 10:52:48,528 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing Grails: Error creating bean with name 'searchableMethodFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'compass' while setting bean property 'compass'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'compass': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: grails/plugin/searchable/internal/compass/mapping/DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder$_buildClassMappingXml_closure1$_closure4$_closure12$_closure13
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'searchableMethodFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'compass' while setting bean property 'compass'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'compass': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: grails/plugin/searchable/internal/compass/mapping/DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder$_buildClassMappingXml_closure1$_closure4$_closure12$_closure13
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'compass': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: grails/plugin/searchable/internal/compass/mapping/DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder$_buildClassMappingXml_closure1$_closure4$_closure12$_closure13
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: grails/plugin/searchable/internal/compass/mapping/DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder$_buildClassMappingXml_closure1$_closure4$_closure12$_closure13
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.mapping.DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder$_buildClassMappingXml_closure1$_closure4$_closure12.doCall(DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder.groovy:188)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.mapping.DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder$_buildClassMappingXml_closure1$_closure4.doCall(DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder.groovy:187)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.mapping.DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder$_buildClassMappingXml_closure1.doCall(DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder.groovy:72)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.mapping.DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder.buildClassMappingXml(DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder.groovy:65)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.config.mapping.SearchableClassPropertySearchableGrailsDomainClassMappingConfigurator.configureMappings(SearchableClassPropertySearchableGrailsDomainClassMappingConfigurator.java:99)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.config.DefaultGrailsDomainClassMappingSearchableCompassConfigurator.configure(DefaultGrailsDomainClassMappingSearchableCompassConfigurator.java:140)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.config.CompositeSearchableCompassConfigurator.configure(CompositeSearchableCompassConfigurator.java:39)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.spring.SearchableCompassFactoryBean.buildCompass(SearchableCompassFactoryBean.java:93)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.spring.SearchableCompassFactoryBean.getObject(SearchableCompassFactoryBean.java:58)
    at grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.spring.SearchableCompassFactoryBean.getObject(SearchableCompassFactoryBean.java:41)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: grails.plugin.searchable.internal.compass.mapping.DefaultSearchableCompassClassMappingXmlBuilder$_buildClassMappingXml_closure1$_closure4$_closure12$_closure13
    ... 14 more
```

To show that this problem is reproducible I have prepared a minimal example on github:

https://github.com/mlist/grails-standalone-search-bug

I created a bug report at: 
https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSTANDALONE-22

I already tried switching from default tomcat 8 to tomcat 7 and jetty (same result). I also tried java 7 and java 8, both with the same result.

Comment: As reported in [this response](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSTANDALONE-22?focusedCommentId=84112&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-84112) "You shouldn't be using the searchable plugin - it only works with Hibernate 3, and it doesn't scale because it uses a local file-based index". So the problem is that the plugin doesn't support directly this execution mode: why don't you answer yourself with the complete explanation. In this way the question could be useful for others in the future.

Comment: You're right, I should have added the response from Burt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer Burt Beckwith gave on my bug report:

> Sorry to do this, but I can't spend any time working on this issue.
>   You shouldn't be using the searchable plugin - it only works with
>   Hibernate 3, and it doesn't scale because it uses a local file-based
>   index. It's based on Compass
>   (http://sourceforge.net/projects/compass/files/compass/), which was
>   last updated in 2009. ElasticSearch is a much better option - see
>   http://thedudeabides.com/articles/the_future_of_compass/